# How to add a external link to anythingslider?

Tags: anythingslider

recently i've implemented the anythingslider module in the main page of my joomla website. it works perfectly. But I want to put an external link(e.g. click the first slide, a new window popup or go to the link straightway) on the first slide. I don't how to add the link and which file I should modify with my limited CSS knowledge. If anyone can give me some suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [latest version](https://github.com/ProLoser/AnythingSlider) of AnythingSlider?

There was a problem with external links inside of the panels in older versions, but it should be resolved in the latest version.

Also, here is [a demo of links inside the panels](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/VM8XG/2952/) - links to change the panel and go to external pages.